# How to search/find specific word In JSON Array with java

Tags: java, json

I have a below JSON Array from the below, I want to get commandResponse associated with searched Command.

e.g. lets say I searched command "show version", It should return my commandResponse as 16.0.1.

JSON Array

```
[{"commandResponse":"","errorMessage":"harddisk crash not applicable.","name":"harddiskcrash","command":"harddiskcrash","status":"NotApplicable"},{"commandResponse":"","errorMessage":"stby-harddisk crash not applicable.","name":"stby-harddiskcrash","command":"stby-harddiskcrash","status":"NotApplicable"},{"commandResponse":"16.0.1","errorMessage":"_showconfigall not applicable.","name":"show_version","command":"show version","status":"NotApplicable"},{"commandResponse":"","errorMessage":"_showpolicy-map not applicable.","name":"_showpolicy-map","command":"_showpolicy-map","status":"NotApplicable"},{"commandResponse":"","errorMessage":"system dirvarlog not applicable.","name":"show version log","command":"show version log","status":"NotApplicable"}]
```

Note: If you see JSON data show version word is present 2 times, show version & show version log but it should return only show version command data.

I tried to do this using JsonPath:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> finalDataList = commandsData.read("$[?(@.command == 'Show Version')]");
```

But it gives me below error:

```
The method parse(String) is undefined for the type JsonPath
```

Notes:

- JSON parser Library - com.googlecode.json-simple
- commandsData - This is JSON Array

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: Use **JsonPath** to query your json - https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it was easier to map JSONArray to Map<String,Object> and implement functionality there!

Below is attached my code on kotlin

```
fun main() {
val json =
    "[{\"commandResponse\":\"\",\"errorMessage\":\"harddisk crash not applicable.\",\"name\":\"harddiskcrash\",\"command\":\"harddiskcrash\",\"status\":\"NotApplicable\"},{\"commandResponse\":\"\",\"errorMessage\":\"stby-harddisk crash not applicable.\",\"name\":\"stby-harddiskcrash\",\"command\":\"stby-harddiskcrash\",\"status\":\"NotApplicable\"},{\"commandResponse\":\"16.0.1\",\"errorMessage\":\"_showconfigall not applicable.\",\"name\":\"show_version\",\"command\":\"show version\",\"status\":\"NotApplicable\"},{\"commandResponse\":\"\",\"errorMessage\":\"_showpolicy-map not applicable.\",\"name\":\"_showpolicy-map\",\"command\":\"_showpolicy-map\",\"status\":\"NotApplicable\"},{\"commandResponse\":\"\",\"errorMessage\":\"system dirvarlog not applicable.\",\"name\":\"show version log\",\"command\":\"show version log\",\"status\":\"NotApplicable\"}]"
val array = JSONParser().parse(json) as JSONArray
println(findCommandResponseByCommand("show version",array))
}

fun findCommandResponseByCommand(command: String, jsonArray: JSONArray): String {
    val found = jsonArray
        .map { it as Map<String, Any> }
        .find { it["command"] == command }
    return found?.get("commandResponse") as? String ?: ""
}
```

The output is

```
16.0.1
```

Added java code

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String json =
            "[{\"commandResponse\":\"\",\"errorMessage\":\"harddisk crash not applicable.\",\"name\":\"harddiskcrash\",\"command\":\"harddiskcrash\",\"status\":\"NotApplicable\"},{\"commandResponse\":\"\",\"errorMessage\":\"stby-harddisk crash not applicable.\",\"name\":\"stby-harddiskcrash\",\"command\":\"stby-harddiskcrash\",\"status\":\"NotApplicable\"},{\"commandResponse\":\"16.0.1\",\"errorMessage\":\"_showconfigall not applicable.\",\"name\":\"show_version\",\"command\":\"show version\",\"status\":\"NotApplicable\"},{\"commandResponse\":\"\",\"errorMessage\":\"_showpolicy-map not applicable.\",\"name\":\"_showpolicy-map\",\"command\":\"_showpolicy-map\",\"status\":\"NotApplicable\"},{\"commandResponse\":\"\",\"errorMessage\":\"system dirvarlog not applicable.\",\"name\":\"show version log\",\"command\":\"show version log\",\"status\":\"NotApplicable\"}]";
    JSONArray array = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(json) ;
    System.out.println(findCommandResponseByCommand("show version",array));
}

private static String findCommandResponseByCommand(String command, JSONArray jsonArray) {
    Optional result = jsonArray.stream()
            .filter(json ->  ((Map<String, Object>) json).get("command").equals(command))
            .findAny();
    if(result.isPresent()){
        return ((Map<String, Object>) result.get()).get("commandResponse").toString();
    }
    return "";
}
}
```

Comment: getting error when I try to put above function in Java code.

Answer (score 2):

To find the required JSON-object in the array, you need to iterate over array elements and check if it contains the target value (like `"Show Version"`). If the matching object was found, you need to extract the value that corresponds to `"commandResponse"` from it.

Here's how it might be implemented using Stream API (`JSONArray` is a subtype of `ArrayList` therefore we can invoke `stream()` on it):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static String getResponse(JSONArray array, String search) {
    
    return (String) array.stream()
        .filter(jsonObject -> ((JSONObject) jsonObject).values().stream()
            .anyMatch(s1 -> ((String) s1).equalsIgnoreCase(search))
        )
        .map(jsonObject -> ((JSONObject) jsonObject).get("commandResponse"))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse("given value doesn't exist"); // apply other methods like orElseThrow() depending on your needs
}
```

*Usage example:*

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    String json = "[{\"commandResponse\":\"\",\"errorMessage\":\"harddisk crash not applicable.\",\"name\":\"harddiskcrash\",\"command\":\"harddiskcrash\",\"status\":\"NotApplicable\"},{\"commandResponse\":\"\",\"errorMessage\":\"stby-harddisk crash not applicable.\",\"name\":\"stby-harddiskcrash\",\"command\":\"stby-harddiskcrash\",\"status\":\"NotApplicable\"},{\"commandResponse\":\"16.0.1\",\"errorMessage\":\"_showconfigall not applicable.\",\"name\":\"show_version\",\"command\":\"show version\",\"status\":\"NotApplicable\"},{\"commandResponse\":\"\",\"errorMessage\":\"_showpolicy-map not applicable.\",\"name\":\"_showpolicy-map\",\"command\":\"_showpolicy-map\",\"status\":\"NotApplicable\"},{\"commandResponse\":\"\",\"errorMessage\":\"system dirvarlog not applicable.\",\"name\":\"show version log\",\"command\":\"show version log\",\"status\":\"NotApplicable\"}]";
    JSONArray array = (JSONArray) parser.parse(json);
    System.out.println(getResponse(array, "Show Version"));
}
```

*Output:*

```
16.0.1
```

**Note:** I would not recommend using `org.json.simple` for any task apart from very trivial. It is very unflexible, and not type-safe. Its `JSONArray` extends `ArrayList` of **row type**, for that reason type casts pop up all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider another library *Josson* to do the job.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson commandsData = Josson.fromJsonString("[{\"commandResponse\":\"\",\"errorMessage\":\"harddisk crash not applicable.\",\"name\":\"harddiskcrash\",\"command\":\"harddiskcrash\",\"status\":\"NotApplicable\"},{\"commandResponse\":\"\",\"errorMessage\":\"stby-harddisk crash not applicable.\",\"name\":\"stby-harddiskcrash\",\"command\":\"stby-harddiskcrash\",\"status\":\"NotApplicable\"},{\"commandResponse\":\"16.0.1\",\"errorMessage\":\"_showconfigall not applicable.\",\"name\":\"show_version\",\"command\":\"show version\",\"status\":\"NotApplicable\"},{\"commandResponse\":\"\",\"errorMessage\":\"_showpolicy-map not applicable.\",\"name\":\"_showpolicy-map\",\"command\":\"_showpolicy-map\",\"status\":\"NotApplicable\"},{\"commandResponse\":\"\",\"errorMessage\":\"system dirvarlog not applicable.\",\"name\":\"show version log\",\"command\":\"show version log\",\"status\":\"NotApplicable\"}]");
String response = commandsData.getString("[command='show version'].commandResponse");
System.out.println(response);
```

**Output**

```
16.0.1
```